# How can I move bytes from a slice into the middle of an array without cloning

Tags: rust

I'm trying to overwrite the payload of a packet. I currently have the following code, it works but benchmarking via perf has shown that cloning the payload of every packet has a significant overhead. What's the best way of doing this without cloning? I'm not afraid of unsafe if it's more efficient.

```rust
struct Packet {
    buffer: [u8; 1613],
}

impl Packet {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            buffer: [0; 1613],
        }
    }

    fn clone_into_buffer(&mut self, src: &[u8; 1613]) {
        self.buffer.clone_from_slice(src);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut packet = Packet::new();

    packet.clone_into_buffer(&[1; 1613]);
}
```

[playground link](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=de733ae8ac02fc2a35cfb373e962117e)

Comment: As the doc says, "If src implements Copy, it can be more performant to use copy_from_slice." https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.clone_from_slice

Comment: I don't think the solution is to improve the copy, you should avoid the copy. Use directly the buffer instead of having a temporary slice payload

Comment: @Stargateur I've added the example

Comment: @Stargateur If you're going to modify some other slice there's no way around cloning or copying. If you're creating a new slice altogether you'll also have to clone or copy. If you want to avoid all sorts of clones and copies you'll have to use another data structure, which'll be more complicated and probably perform worse than just modifying a couple of bytes in a slice.

Comment: I've managed to get a version working by using [swap_with_slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.swap_with_slice) although this doesn't seem to run much better in my benchmark. It seems to use copy_nonoverlapping under the hood.

Comment: What you will do with another language is probably copy the whole payload as a whole (3 short integers, it's nothing). That's what `copy_fom_slice` does. The only way to get faster would be to directly write the ints at the right place from the start, I guess.

Comment: @Cubic https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=af5a4bb88af1acf0a06e86d032611bb3 ? I didn't understand your note

Comment: @DenysSéguret The amount that I'm copying in the real world code is variable and could be hundreds of bytes.

Comment: You only show how you do the clone, and the only other option semantically equivalent to that is copy. If you want to avoid copying, you need to show how you want to *use* the packet, because then there are options to come up with a way to share or transfer ownership of the data. It will probably use some variant of the `split`*`_mut` slice method, and some kind of smart pointer. But without larger context we don't know which is appropriate.